# play sound based on the number of times listed on a textfield

Tags: ios, swift, loops, int, textfield

My code below is has a textfield and a sound function. I would like the user to have the sound file be played the number of times the int is in the textfield when the button is pressed.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var sam : UITextField!
    var bombSoundEffect: AVAudioPlayer?

    func judo(){
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "example.mp3", ofType:nil)!
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        do {
            bombSoundEffect = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            bombSoundEffect?.play()
        } catch {
            // couldn't load file :(
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Please use numberOfLoops:**
>        "numberOfLoops" is the number of times that the sound will return to the beginning upon reaching the end. 
>       A value of zero means to play the sound just once.
>       A value of one will result in playing the sound twice, and so on..
>       Any negative number will loop indefinitely until stopped.

```
bombSoundEffect.numberOfLoops = 1
```

You can do this in another way with some delay:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    var player = AVAudioPlayer()
    var timer = Timer()
    var count: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func playAction(_ sender: Any) {

        let alertSound = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "stereo", ofType: "wav")!)

        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: alertSound)
        } catch {
            print("No sound found by URL")
        }

        if let textValue = self.textField.text, let inputNumber = Int(textValue), inputNumber > 0 {
            playWith(repeatCount: inputNumber)
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Please enter number.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    func playWith(repeatCount: Int) {

        player.play()
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.36, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            self.count += 1
            print(self.count)
            if self.count != repeatCount {
                self.player.play()
            } else {
                self.count  = 0
                self.player.stop()
                self.timer.invalidate()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**This is exactly what you want. In this demo, you have to enter input number in the text field and after that sound will play input number times.**

If you want that time interval will also dynamic means time interval will also come from textField2 then use this method:

```
func playWith(repeatCount: Int) {

        var timeInterval = 0.36
        if let textValue = self.textField2.text, let inputNumber = Double(textValue), inputNumber > 0 {
            timeInterval = inputNumber
        }

        player.play()
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            self.count += 1
            print(self.count)
            if self.count != repeatCount {
                self.player.play()
            } else {
                self.count  = 0
                self.player.stop()
                self.timer.invalidate()
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: How could I do that with a 3 second delay between each sound effect.

Comment: You have to use the timer with the delay to achieve this.

Comment: Is this part of the code Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: true making the code go on a 3 second delay for a endless amount of time.

Comment: I don think all of the code is listed. There is no var for timer. Could you please add all of the code.Thanks.

Comment: I was able to run all of the code and this is partially what I was looking for. But What I want was there to be a textfield where you put a int in. The Int in the textfield determines how many times the audio file should repeat.

Comment: So I deal the textfield would say 5. Then you would have the sound go off 5 times in 3 seconds intervals between. That is exactly what I am looking for thanks!

Comment: I have updated my answer and this time you can find full implementation with repeat sound exactly what you want.

Comment: Could you take a look at this question right here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245231/use-textfield-to-create-intervals-between-sounds-being-played-swift4. Its just a add on part from this question. Thanks

Comment: Ok, Let me check

Comment: @SamBurns: your question is put on hold off-topic So not have answer window for your question

Comment: Your the man! Could you answer it on raywenderlich https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/use-textfield-to-create-intervals-between-sounds-being-played/42422.